# How to run official elasticsearch vagrant boxes

Tags: elasticsearch, vagrant

Where can I find documentation for elasticsearch vagrant boxes? Or how should I use them?

Boxes: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/elastic

I did execute these vagrant commands:

```
vagrant init elastic/ubuntu-16.04-x86_64
vagrant up --provider virtualbox
```

Expected elastic search to be running inside virtual box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Expected elastic search to be running inside virtual box

yep, why ? Its nowhere said that elasticsearch will be running in the VM (and if running, which version, which setup) - although it might be cool

Those boxes are mainly used for elastic (as the company) to run their own test. You find more information about that in their github repo

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/TESTING.asciidoc#testing-scripts

and an example of the Vagrantfile they're using

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/Vagrantfile

Comment: Thank you. Very good question. Initially tried to use docker to run elastic search. Image from docker hub says deprecated, recommended registry did not work (timeout). Therefore had similar expectations for Vagrant setup.